# Can't get MySQL workbench to work

Tags: 11.10, mysql, deb

I've installed Ubuntu 11.10 and can't seem to get MySQL workbench to work.  I have tried installing both versions from the website by downloading the .deb files for ubuntu 10.04 and 11.04, but both give the same problem.

The problem I get is when I click on a connection, it asks for a password and that's it, it just displays a never ending "please wait.

From the terminal, I used to create a tunnel using the command:

```
ssh -L 3306:localhost:3306 username_here@ip_address_here
```

But then I discovered MySQL workbench for Ubuntu 10.04 and it worked perfectly.  I just can't get it to work on 11.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Temporary fix until Oracle fix it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:olivier-berten/misc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench-gpl
```